# Setting the svg code as the background of a div

Tags: css, svg, background-image, svg-filters

```
<svg width="40" height="30" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"> 
<filter id="glow">
<fegaussianblur stddeviation="2"/>
</filter>
 <path filter="url(#glow)" transform="translate(5 5)" d="M0 0 L15 20 L30 0" style="fill:transparent; stroke:white; stroke-width:3; stroke-linejoin: round; stroke-linecap: round" />
</svg>
```

This is the svg I wrote, I want to set it as the background of a div, I've tried every way I saw on the internet.

I've tried to save it as a svg file and wrote this `background-image: url("imgs/tick.svg");`

I've tried to use it like this `url('data:image/svg+xml,--svg code--')`

What should I do?

By the way, when I simplify the svg (like `<svg width="40" height="30" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"> <path transform="translate(5 5)" d="M0 0 L15 20 L30 0" style="fill:transparent; stroke:black; stroke-width:5; stroke-linejoin: round; stroke-linecap: round" /></svg>`), it works. Why do this work and the other one doesn't?

Comment: SVG is case sensitive unless it's embedded within something that isn't such as HTML. The correct tag name is therefore feGaussianBlur

Comment: @RobertLongson Thank you, it worked when I create a svg file and use it with URL. After this point, it isn't too necessary but is there a way to make this without creating a separate file, to use all code in css?

Comment: Yes, the data URL approach you reference in the question already.